# How improve text detection for bad quality image?

Tags: python, opencv

Usually, threshold and text detection is good for good quality image but bad image is really not good.
I think the bad image needs some preprocessing but I don't know how.
Do you have any idea to improve text detection for bad quality image?

```py
import sys
import cv2
import math

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, bw = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_DILATE, (5, 5))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(grad, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * peri, True)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    if math.fabs(cv2.contourArea(approx)) > 100:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('rects', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

- good qaulity image
  [image: good quality image]
- bad quality image
  [image: bad quality image]

Comment: Try using adaptive thresholding and morphology to preprocess your image to black/white first.

Comment: Look at convolutional neural networks. See this paper:  'Classification of low resolution astronomical images using convolutional neural networks - https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8256782'

Comment: You can use Otsu's thresholding to obtain a binary image then perform morphological operations to smooth/enhance the image. Could you add the original input image?